# Why does using GetPixel result in an "undefined reference"?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include<stdio.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL); 
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 10, 10); 
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    cout << color;

    return 0;
}
```

There's a error said :

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `GetPixel@12'   
 ld returned 1 exit status    
[Build Error]  [Project1.exe] Error 1
```

I m using Dev-C++ complier

Comment: How to add gdi32.lib. Well, it depends on your compiler.

Comment: Switch from Dev-C++ to Code::Blocks, DC++ is horribly outdated.

Comment: @JBL: In project options, try adding this line `-lgdi32`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `Gdi32.lib` to your dependency list. The `GetPixel()` function is not in the default libraries.

EDIT:

In Visual Studio, you can add dependencies like this:

Menu: Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input

The "Additional Dependencies" option will look like this:

`kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Add `Gdi32.lib` to it.

Comment: #pragma comment (lib, "gdi32.lib")
E: From his error output, that doesn't look like VS, looks like Dev Cpp.

Comment: @Tanner: I didn't know you could do that. :)

Comment: @Tanner: I think its only specific to MSVC++ compilers.

Comment: Ah, Dev-C++... It's been a long time since I've used it. You'll have to look it up since I don't know.

Comment: @cpx Oh dear, you are definitely right on that one. My update will be to add -lgdi32.lib as a compiler command. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Dev-C++ is horribly outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I was given that error and I solved it by scrapping **Visual Studio Code** as my IDE and switching over to **Visual Studio 2019**. VS19 solved my dependency error automatically! I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score -2):

In order to use the Win32 API you need to create a Windows Application.

This means using a WinMain function instead of a main() function.

It can (optional) also include creating a window and processing window messages with a window procedure.

After you do that, then you will be able to call the Win32 API GetPixel.

If you insist on creating a console or non-windows application, then you would have to define your own GetPixel which would probably access video memory directly.

So, start by creating a WinMain function instead of a main().  (Of course you'll need to link to the appropriate libraries as well.)

Comment: You don't need a WinMain func to use the WinAPI, how do you think File I/O works in console apps?

Comment: -1, You can use the Win32 API from a Windows console application.  Such applications typically use main() rather than WinMain.